# Spotfire dynamic filtering

Tags: data-visualization, spotfire

I have a file which consists of a few part numbers.Using this file i need to exclude data in dashboard in  another table which also has part numbers.How to filter data out of the table based on the part numbers present in the file if the part numbers in the file can change over time?

Comment: this will be a lot easier to answer if you provide some sample data

Answer (score 0):

When you import the file with a list of part numbers, add a calculated column under transformations (also make sure that it's not reading the first record of your part list file as a header row--I don't know what your file looks like). In the expression box, just enter something simple like `1`. Call this new dataset something like `part_list`. This column represents a flag that we will add to the table that is already in your dashboard. Let's suppose that table is called `data`.

Once the file is imported, click Insert > Columns... and ensure that `data` is selected in the "Add columns to data table:" drop down box, and that `part_list` is selected in the "Add columns from:" menu. Click Next. Match the part number column in both tables, and click next. Add the flag column to `data` with a left outer join (assuming this makes sense with your data). Once the column is added, you can filter out the 1's.

If this does not answer your question, consider providing more details about what your data looks like.